# How to expose grouping in Views?

Tags: 7, views

I have a **view**, where I **use grouping** to display publications by year. 
Format: HTML List -> Settings -> Grouping field Nr.1: Year
[image]

This is what I get:

[image]

Is there a possibility, to **expose this grouping** to the website user? So that the user can group for example by publications type or author? So the same functionality like exposing filters?

Comment: You could create multiple pages on the view with tabs, each tab-view using a different grouping. The user will then pick the tab to get the grouping desired. You could also use [QuickTabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs).

Comment: Using tabs and multiple pages is the hint. Thanks alot for your tip :-) For people with the same problem, I posted a step-by-step explanation here.

Answer (score 0):

kiamlaluno gave the perfect hint. Without actually using any additional modules, you can just use tabbing for multiple views, each with different grouping.
Thats how you do it:

1. Create a new view as a page
2. Page settings -> Menu -> Path -> e.g. /publications
3. No Menu link

[image]

4. Add a new page to the view with the same credentials like the one above (in my case grouping by field_year) - IMPORTANT
5. Page settings -> Menu -> Path -> e.g. /publications/by-year (keep the root path)
6. Page settings -> Menu -> Default menu tab
7. Parent menu item -> Default menu item

[image]

8. Add a new page to the view with different credentials (in my case grouping by field_type)
9. Page settings -> Menu -> Path -> e.g. /publications/by-type (keep the root path)
10. Page settings -> Menu -> Menu tab

[image]

Finally there are three pages:

[image]

In the frontend it will look like this:

[image]

I hope this steps help you a bit. In this way, you can create as many views as you like.

Thanks to the community again.